# How to get the TableViewCell above (or below) a specific TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Could anyone tell me how to access the UITableViewCell above (or below) a specific cell?  I have access to the cell the user is selecting using didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell?
}
```

And I know how to access the cell's row number:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var currentRowNum = indexPath.row
}
```

Is there a way to access cells one row above or below?

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: create a new indexPath with the row number decreased by one and then get the cell by that indexPath!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get like this.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        //Current cell...       
       var currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell?

       //Next cell...
       let nextIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row + 1, inSection: indexPath.section)
       var nextCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(nextIndex) as UITableViewCell?

      //Previous cell...
      let prevIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row - 1, inSection: indexPath.section)
      var prevCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(prevIndex) as UITableViewCell?
}
```